# How to group by a df in Python by a column with the difference between the max value of one column and the min of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which looks like this:

| student_id | session_id | reading_level_id | st_week | end_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3334 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3335 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 3335 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3336 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3337 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 3339 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

...

There are multiple session_id's, st_weeks and end_weeks for every student_id. Im trying to group the data by 'student_id' and I want to calculate the difference between the maximum(end_week) and the minimum (st_week) for each student.

Aiming for an output that would look something like this:

| Student_id | Diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

....

I am relatively new to Python as well as Stack Overflow and have been trying to find an appropriate solution - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular do not share code as image.

Comment: Hi, thank you! just edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data you shared, a simpler solution is possible:

Group by `student_id`, and pass `False` argument to the `as_index` parameter (this works for a dataframe, and returns a dataframe);

Next, use a [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to get the `max week for end week and the min week for st_week for each group

Get the difference between `max_wk` and `end_wk`

Finally, keep only the required columns

```
(
    df.groupby("student_id", as_index=False)
    .agg(max_wk=("end_week", "max"), min_wk=("st_week", "min"))
    .assign(Diff=lambda x: x["max_wk"] - x["min_wk"])
    .loc[:, ["student_id", "Diff"]]
)

    student_id  Diff
0          1    1
1          2    2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but I broke this into separate steps for the grouping to get max and min values for each id, and then created a new column representing the difference. I used numpy's `randint()` function in this example because I didn't have access to a sample dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1200, 4)), columns=['student_id', 'session_id', 'st_week', 'end_week'])
# use groupby to get max and min for each student_id
max_vals = df.groupby(['student_id'], sort=False)['end_week'].max().to_frame()
min_vals = df.groupby(['student_id'], sort=False)['st_week'].min().to_frame()
# use join to put max and min back together in one dataframe 
merged = min_vals.join(max_vals)
# use assign() to calculate difference as new column
merged = merged.assign(difference=lambda x: x.end_week - x.st_week).reset_index()
merged
student_id  st_week end_week    difference
0   40  2   99  97
1   23  5   74  69
2   78  9   93  84
3   11  1   97  96
4   97  24  88  64
... ... ... ... ...
95  54  0   96  96
96  18  0   99  99
97  8   18  97  79
98  75  21  97  76
99  33  14  93  79
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. Perhaps there's a more succinct solution out there but this has solved the issue for me. SO is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function and apply it to a group-by over students:

```py
def week_diff(g):
    return g.end_week.max() - g.st_week.min()
df.groupby("student_id").apply(week_diff)
```

Result:

```
student_id
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```